# Is there a UI framework to emulate the look of a Mac app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, desktop

I've been looking around and havent been able to find any. I noticed that the wunderlist mac app was written in HTML/CSS/JS but I wasnt sure if they used an existing UI javascript framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wunderlist was created using the Titanium framework (http://www.appcelerator.com/).

Titanium is used to create cross-platform applications for Windows, Mac, mobile platforms, and others.

If you're wondering how they got the Mac "look", that's because Titanium has built in Mac-like UI controls as part of the framework.

#### Edit

Here's the Titanium Desktop page: http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/

> Titanium makes Vista apps look like Vista apps, XP apps like XP apps and Mac OS X apps fully native as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I took a look around the documentation but didn't find any mention of this. Is it considered a separate project?

Comment: @simonwjackson Well, of course, they don't release a UI kit. What they really do is release an application that you use to compile your code using their framework. See http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/: "Titanium makes Vista apps look like Vista apps, XP apps like XP apps and Mac OS X apps fully native as well".